# How do I remove invalid `redirect_uri` parameter to access Keycloak admin console?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I am in the process of upgrading from Keycloak v17.0.0 to v18.0.2 and I am running into a problem accessing the admin console. The relevant section of the [upgrading guide](https://dev.auth.airtonomy.ai/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.auth.airtonomy.ai%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=ebd7ca01-a577-4f99-9b20-3f3272f23f3e&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=718cd50d-58eb-4305-a7b2-4c6271f60277&code_challenge=wyeWwW9LyRVySf1b2eVAQ93z2GYKpvoblGCm987utBc&code_challenge_method=S256) describes needing to remove the `redirect_uri` parameter and replacing it with the `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameters. I've worked with my frontend team to ensure that we are not relying on the `redirect_uri` parameter in our application code and signing in and out of our application works normally on both versions 17 and 18. The problem is that on version 17.0.0 we are able to access the admin console. Normally we would do this by navigating to the page shown in the first screenshot clicking on "Administration Console" but when trying to do the same thing on version 18.0.2 clicking that link brings us to the second screenshot which says "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri". The thing that's confusing to me is that the Admin Welcome screen is not something we control the code for. I'm not aware of any way I can affect the address (or parameters) that that link on the welcome screen directs to.

[Admin Welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ab0i.png)
[Error trying to access admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WQyP.png)

What should I do to get access to the Admin Console on v18? Is there something that I need to change in the Admin Console before making this upgrade? If so, will going backward from v18 to v17 cause any problems? Does it seem at all likely that this would be resolved by proceeding to v19 or V20?

Based on my reading about this issue I'm still not 100% sure if "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" means that the parameter is not allowed at all or if it means that it is expected and I have supplied an incorrect value for it.

I've tried manually removing the `redirect_uri` from the address and doing so doesn't change anything, the same page loads, still saying it's receiving an invalid parameter even though it is not present in the query string.

We are running Keycloak as a nomad job and using the following configuration to start the container:

```
image_args:
        - "--db-url=jdbc:postgresql://{{ host.db.host }}:{{ host.db.port | default(5432) }}/{{ prefix(tenant, 'keycloak') }}"
        - "--db-username= *** "
        - "--db-password= *** "
        - "--proxy=edge"
        - "--hostname={{ host.hostnames[0] }}"
        - "--log-level=debug"
        - "--spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true"
        {% if host | traverse("services:keycloak:migrate_db", false) %}
        - "--spi-connections-jpa-default-migration-strategy=update"
        {% endif %}
      env:
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: {{ salt["sdb.get"]("sdb://aws_deploy/" + prefix(tenant, "keycloak/admin", "/")) }}
```